# How to center text in SVG?

Tags: html, svg

I need to center text horizontally inside  tag in SVG object without need to define x coordinate. I'm trying to find an alternative to text-align: center in CSS. I've already used text-anchor: middle but it doesn't work.
I have this code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
 <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFE89C" stop-opacity="1"/>
 <stop offset="0.2" stop-color="#FFE192" stop-opacity="1"/>
 <stop offset="0.4" stop-color="#ffd47a" stop-opacity="1"/>
 <stop offset="0.6" stop-color="#ffc967" stop-opacity="1"/>
 <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="#febd52" stop-opacity="1"/>
 <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fdba4c" stop-opacity="1"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<text fill="url(#grad1)" x="73" y="50">50</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: `text-anchor: middle` is the correct method.  There isn't really any other way to do it.  What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: The text is centered relatively x-axis, and I want that it' center relatively parent SVG container, otherwise it turn out that if the length of text content changes, it will be necessary to change the x coordinate. It seems that there is no another way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The text is centered relatively x-axis, and I want that it' center
>   relatively parent SVG container, otherwise it turn out that if the
>   length of text content changes, it will be necessary to change the x
>   coordinate.

You just need to position the text at a location halfway across the `viewBox`.  Then if you use `text-anchor="middle"`, the text will stay centred.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 150 60">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFE89C" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="0.2" stop-color="#FFE192" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="0.4" stop-color="#ffd47a" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="0.6" stop-color="#ffc967" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="#febd52" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fdba4c" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <text fill="url(#grad1)" x="75" y="50" text-anchor="middle"font-size="40">50</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul, now I've got it

Answer (score 0):

### Centering a non-text object in CSS

I haven't tested this within an SVG block, but this is the CSS to make most anything centered within a div. I use it wherever I need a centered item and text-align is not appropriate.

In a nutshell: use auto width, left and right and give it a total width parameter.

```
// Classes
.center-block {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;  // Use whatever percentage of the container width you need
}
```

All 3 parameters are required or it will not center.

Answer (score 0):

**text-anchor="middle"** by using this attribute of the svg element you can make your svg element's text aligned.!